# Compiling/executing Java on Sublime Text 2 works fine except that it cannot read user input

Tags: java, sublime-text-2

I am a student learning Java and I want to compile and run some simple Java on ST2. Also Eclipse is very slow on my laptop.

Here is my JavaC.sublime-build file so far:

```
{
    "cmd": ["sublimejavaexec.bat", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

So far it can run code that does not require user input. However when I have something that uses the Java input scanner it either skips through or generates an error.

Can anyone suggest a solution such as a plug-in or if ST2 actually has this kind of feature on its console?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

just create a javacr bash/bat with something like

```
#!/bin/sh
javac $1.java
java $1
```

and inside your JavaC.sublime-build:

```
{
  "cmd":["javacr","$file_base_name"],
  "file_regex": "^(...?):([0-9]):?([0-9]*)", 
  "selector": "source.java" 
}
```